# in sql inserting from one table to another without dupes

Tags: sql-server-2008

this worked once before for me but the script is not working now
i want toinsert into another table but without any dupes......

```
 select * from [Data_Guru].[dbo].[MORTGAGE_AUG_27_new_1] 
 where Phone not in (select Phone from [dbo].MASTER_LIST)
```

that is the bottom part that i am having trouble with when i change it to another table it shows all of the numbers that are not in that table. and i do know for a fact that there shouldnt be many if any duplicate records in the 2 tables.. they are complete different categories....pleas help

Comment: Uh, "select distinct" maybe ;)?

Comment: i tried that. this is frustrating because it worked the first time i did it last week and now it works with one table  but not the main one... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem with "in" and "not in" queries is the presence of NULL.  Try this:

```
select *
from [Data_Guru].[dbo].[MORTGAGE_AUG_27_new_1]
where Phone not in (select Phone from [dbo].MASTER_LIST where Phone is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct * from [Data_Guru].[dbo].[MORTGAGE_AUG_27_new_1] t1
where NOT EXISTS (select Phone from [dbo].MASTER_LIST where t1.phone=t2.phone)
```